# How do you call a javascript function with a HTML button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, I'm trying to make a dice roller that can, you guessed it!, roll dice. I want to call a javascript function within a HTML button click. I know this is very easy with angular, but I am not using Angular. I am using jQuery, but I don't want to make the whole thing jQuery, however, if I have to, I will. Anyway, I am trying to make a button that adds a die, one that removes a die, one that adds a side to the dice, and one that removes a side from the dice. Oh, and one that rolls the dice, but I've already coded that in.
Here's my HTML (note: I am using jQuery so it might look a little weird):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#button0").click(function(){
        diceRoll = 0
        for (i=diceAmt;i>0;i--) {
          diceRoll += rand(1, diceSides)
        }
        document.getElementById("dieRoll").innerHTML = diceRoll;
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="screen">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="text">
          <span id="dieRoll"></span>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <button class="button1" id="button0"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <button class="button2">Add die</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button class="button3">Remove die</button>
        <br/>
        <button class="button2">Add side</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button class="button3">Remove side</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript (again might look a little weird):

```js
var diceAmt = 2
var diceSides = 6
var diceRoll
var xDx = diceAmt+"d"+diceSides
function floor(num){let n1=Math.round(num);let n2=n1-1;if(n1>num){return n2}else{return n1}}
function rand(num1,num2){let n1=num2+1-num1;let n2=floor(Math.random()*n1)+num2;return n2}
function addDie () {
  diceAmt += 1
  xDx = diceAmt+"d"+diceSides
  document.getElementById("button0").innerHTML = "Roll "+xDx
}
function rmoveDie () {
  diceAmt -= 1
  xDx = diceAmt+"d"+diceSides
  document.getElementById("button0").innerHTML = "Roll "+xDx
}
function addSide () {
  diceSides += 1
  xDx = diceAmt+"d"+diceSides
  document.getElementById("button0").innerHTML = "Roll "+xDx
}
function rmoveSide () {
  diceSides -= 1
  xDx = diceAmt+"d"+diceSides
  document.getElementById("button0").innerHTML = "Roll "+xDx
}
```

Now, I would normally show you my CSS here, but the CSS doesn't matter.
Oh, I almost forgot to show you the libraries I'm using. Here they are:

[jquery.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js)

I would really like it if you could help me out here.

## Thank you!

(Note: I would normally do that part in code but I figured it would be cooler if it was an actual h1.)

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: Try the HTML onclick="" attribute and pass your function

Comment: @TEK okay, I will.

Comment: ^ that is exactly _not_ what you want to do. It requires global functions (which are a bad thing already in themselves) and prevent you from setting a [more secure content security policy](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/adopting-csp.html) to mitigate XSS attacks.

Comment: @mlibby uhh... You know what, I have words that I don't want to say here.

Comment: nevermind then...

Comment: How are you going to make a XSS attack with the code he has shown us?

Comment: Seriously. You've already got code that executes a function on a button click. `$("#button0").click(...)`. It might not work because you have JS that is being parsed/evaluated before the DOM is loaded. You should look at jQuery's `ready()` function to fix that. But it helps us answer, if you make your question as short and to-the-point as possible. And try to end with the exact question, what isn't working for you, that sort of thing.

Comment: @TEK: Not right now. But it's a general point. We don't want to teach people bad practices just because they are not that bad that one time.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: O.K., I got it working. I use a testing software called [playcode.io](https://playcode.io), and I tested it there.

Comment: @mlibby oh, that's what you mean. I didn't want to make the whole thing jQuery, so I asked the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever a button is triggered a click `event` is fired. To handle that event there are **3** ways in vanilla javascript:

#### 1. Specifying the function to be called in an HTML tag.

```html
<button class="button2" onclick="addDie()">Add die</button>
```

#### 2. Adding a handler in the button `onclick` property in JS.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("your_button_id");
button.onclick = function(event) {
// do something
}
// or in your case
button.onclick = addDie
```

#### 3. Adding an event listener

With this approach, you can add any number of handler for your event in the button.

```js
button.addEventListener("click", addDie);
button.addEventListener("click", dieRoll);
```

These three are the possible ways to handle the events using vanilla JS.

#### Since you are using jquery you can simply do,

```js
$("#button2").click(addDie)
```

#### To make sure the events are attached safely you would need to wait till the document is loaded.

#### 1. In Jquery

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
...
$("#button2").click(addDie)
...
}
```

#### 2. In Vanilla JS

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
...
 button.addEventListener("click", addDie);
 button.addEventListener("click", dieRoll);
...
});
```

Knowing the above three ways will help you understand the ways events can be handled with vanilla js.

Comment: The jQuery response is the exact issue he is facing.  He needs to use $(function()... or $(document.ready()... to defer execution.

Comment: This is an answer to the _stated_ question, but not to the actual underlying problem the OP had. It's sort of an XY problem, the OP thought that it was an incorrect way to attach a listener, but in fact it was just _too early_ to attach a listener. (Thus they asked the wrong question.) So unfortunately even though it is a good answer, it doesn't solve their issue.

Comment: Oops, my bad I only focused on the part for `How do you call a javascript function with an HTML button click?`  so I only pointed out how you can call a function. I will add that part as well.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code you showed, I think the issue is that your script is in the `head` part, before the body (including the buttons) is even loaded.

That means that when you do `$("#button0")`, you get a collection of *zero elements* (the buttons don't exist yet), and then you attach a `click` handler to zero elements, so you are doing nothing.

The solution is simple: jQuery allows you in a very simple way to defer the execution of some code until the DOM has finished loading. That is done by calling `$` as a function and passing a callback, i.e. `$(...)` (or, more verbosely, by writing `$(document).ready(...)`):

```js
  $(function () {
      $("#button0").click(function(){
        diceRoll = 0
        for (i=diceAmt;i>0;i--) {
          diceRoll += rand(1, diceSides)
        }
        document.getElementById("dieRoll").innerHTML = diceRoll;
      })
  })
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: They are defined, but in the other JS he posted.  I was running it in JSFiddle, if you include that script as well, it works with your answer.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked the second part of the code, since the HTML didn't include any other `<script>`s. Removed that part from my answer.

Comment: I had a separate script containing jQuery v3.5.1. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes don't worry about it, I was just confused because the HTML itself didn't load any other JavaScript, but if (at the moment) it's part of a JSFiddle that is fine.